# Полный перенос лаборатории в PNETlab

Tags: vmware, eve

Можно ли перенести лабораторию PNETLab полностью, чтобы сохранилась конфигурация устройств ? Я знаю что можно сделать экспорт, но тогда сохранится просто топология сети, без сохранения настроек сетевых оборудований.